# pre-compile JavaScript templates to functions on project build

Tags: javascript, jquery-templates

**Update** I want to avoid compiling the templates client-side, and have them compile during my local ant build process. Perhaps something like loading jQuery and jQuery templates into rhino, passing the `$.template()` function the contents of each .jst file in turn, and building a "templates.js" which should contain:

```
$.template['model-view'] = resultingFunction.toString();
// 1 for each .jst file
```

This way, I can maintain each template in a seperate file, and avoid having all clients redundantly compile the same template.

---

I'm using jQuery templates, and was hoping to separate them out into their own files (eg. model-view.jst) that are compiled into functions when the project is built and made available in the jQuery .tmpl() scope for later use.

For example, given the file **model-view.jst**

```
<li>${name}</li>
```

This file and all other .jst files should be picked up on build, compiled into a function that can later be used anywhere in the program like so:

```
$.tmpl('model-view', {
    name: 'Matt'
});
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you expect as the answer - a build script? Because your build step should really just read *.jst files and transform them into something like `modelView = "<li>${name}</li>"` (don't forget to escape string contents properly). Calling `$.tmpl(modelView, {...})` will work then.

Comment: I think you find yourself the solution

Comment: I have a rough idea of what needs to be done, just not exactly how. I think the biggest problem with trying to import jQuery and jQuery templates into rhino is that they require the DOM, which rhino doesn't have. I might see if I can import a "headless" browser into rhino first and go from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using Node.js and coffeescript by making directory of partial templated into executable, pre-compiled functions. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/wookiehangover/jquery-tmpl-jst

Answer (score 0):

I let you decide if you like it or not :)

in you common js library define this function:

```
function loadTemplate(templateName) {
   $.ajax({
      url: templateName + '.jst',
      success: function(data) {
         $.template(templateName, data);
      }});
}
```

Then in you master hml file `<head></head>` section you can add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">loadTemplate('model-view');</script>
<script type="text/javascript">loadTemplate('another-model-view');</script>
```

so you can use anywhere in your code

```
$.tmpl('model-view', your-data)
$.tmpl('another-model-view', your-data)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sending an AJAX request for each template is not really a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't see any other thing. jQuery template should allow things like <script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" src="source.jst"></script> it would be great

Comment: anyway this doesn't answer the question because Matty F doesn't want client side compilation

Comment: It would have to be supported by the browser.. if jQuery supported this it would still require AJAX to load them.